# The professor is said to have been a genius when young

Tags: complements

> The professor is said ***_*__** a genius when young.
>
> 1) that he was
>
> 2) to have been

This is a question from [a English forum](http://k.daum.net/qna/view.html?qid=5EVGD&l_cid=QNE001&l_st=1&returl=/qna/question/list.html?category_id=QNE001&). OP asks he thinks both seems correct, but why is the answer 2) (maybe in his certain book) not correct. I also get the curiosity why 1) cannot be the answer.

Comment: Although I don't know this particular professor, apparently *it is said **that he was** a genius when young.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 2 is correct, and means that there are people who currently say that in the past, the professor was young and a genius.

Number 1 doesn't make sense. I think they're trying to trick you, because if you make a minor change and remove the *is*, then 1 is correct and 2 is not:

> The professor said that he was a genius when young.

This means that the professor himself claims that he was a genius. It's all a bit awkward; I'd prefer *when he was young* to simply *when young*.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, I cannot comprehend the first option.

> (X) The professor is said *that he was* a genius when young.

The above sentence does *not* make any sense to me.

While with second option:

> The professor is said *to have been* a genius when young.

Makes at least a little sense.

With the first option merged in the sentence, there is no clarity who said that the professor was a genius. *Maybe*, remove the word *is* after the subject and the first option would be a fit. Other than that, it doesn't make sense to me.

As for the second option, it makes more sense when it's put together in the sentence, as it means that *someone else (or a rumour)* said that *the professor was a genius.*

Comment: The second one might make sense if it was changed to, "the professor is said to have been a genius since  he was young."